# Is this valid JSON for parsing?

Tags: json, parsing

I've got a task to write a JSON parser in java with a little help.

I'm already able to parse this:

```
{
 "ArrayWithOneString" : [ "ArrayContent" ],
 "Array" : [
   {
      "ArrayinArray" : [
         {
            "NumberInArray" : 1337,
            "StringInArray" : "String"
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've got only one last problem:

```
"string" : { // The bracket
    "string" : "valueString"
},
```

My problem is that I expect a value and not another object for this opening bracket (**{**).
I wanted to ask if this is valid json before trying to parse it.

Comment: To check if a JSON is valid, use **[an online JSON validator or linter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jsonlint)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is valid. Well without your highlighting attempts, and assuming it is part of a parent object.

Just because you have a property called "string" doesn't mean it has to be a string value. I suggest perhaps whoever made it just isn't being very consistent, but it is still valid.

The question is, why are you expecting a value? Either the person who constructed the JSON has not done it to specification, or it is you that is not understanding the specification.

Also, you can easily [validate JSON here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I think its me not understanding the specification since this is an json example of google maps but renamed. So how would i call the content? another object? another string? no number and no array I think.

Comment: You call it whatever you want it to be, something meaningful for the data you are trying to represent. If this is just an example then it isn't of any practical use. Try creating an object for some data that you actual plan on using and give the properties useful names

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.json.org/) for specifications. Your example is valid according to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid JSON. You can now parse in your code.

You can [check Valid JSON](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=dd87cde9c53b9c003ec5eb8863588553)

See below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Yea you didn't read my Question, that's the part I'm already able to parse ^^, the next part is the one im asking if it's valid.